# How to set type of a parameter to Vue Component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a function that takes a component as a parameter in typescript and I want to set its type to 'VueComponent'?

```
function callback(component: VueComponent???){
 // some code
}
```

Comment: which vue version are you using?

Comment: I believe you have to import that component in the file where callback is defined and then you can use that component's name as a type.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Vue 2.6

Comment: @MohammadUsman But I want that different components can be sent to this function.

Comment: @AMD All custom components inherit from 'Vue' so you can try using this as a base component.

Comment: @AMD Alternatively you can try using [Generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following typings

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/types/options.d.ts#L10

```
export type Component<Data=DefaultData<never>, Methods=DefaultMethods<never>, Computed=DefaultComputed, Props=DefaultProps> =
  | typeof Vue
  | FunctionalComponentOptions<Props>
  | ComponentOptions<never, Data, Methods, Computed, Props>
```

Both `Component` and `FunctionalComponentOptions` are exported by the Vue

Comment: There's a lot of different types exported here (`Component`, `ComponentOptions`, `VueConstructor` or even just `Vue`). But none of them actually helps having a right typing / autocompletion: you won't see the properties from the component in parameter. And I think that is the main question here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
import type { Component } from "vue"

function callback(component: Component){
 // some code
}
```